# How to tell what version testers are using in testflight

Tags: testing, testflight

I have a tester reporting a problem but he didn't specify what version of our iOS app he was using. We are using TestFlight and I was wondering if there is a way of finding this out? I can see what hardware he is using but it doesn't go into specifics regarding the app itself.

I normally just email for this but it would be quicker to know this information right away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If pick a particular build and go through to 'Activity' under 'Reports' then you should see a column titled 'Status'. That'll tell you which users have installed that build on which of their devices.

Comment: Is going through the builds individually the only way to find this out? We have a lot of builds